# Getting according to auto scroll to content in React using Semantic-UI React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using the "styled" accordion found here: https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/accordion/

I am trying to initiate an auto scroll when the user clicks on the dropdown (an image in my case) for an accordion. As of right now, my code allows for the image (the 'Post' component, which is simply a Card object that displays an image and some teaser text) to be clicked, and the content is then rendered below the image.

I would like to have the window scroll to the content on click, so that the user does not have to scroll down after clicking on the . I have tried using Refs, but I don't seem to be doing this correctly. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. Here is my code:

```
 import React, { Component, useRef, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Accordion } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import Post from './Post';
import AudioPlayer from './AudioPlayer';
export default class PostContent extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      activeIndex: 0 
    }
  }

  handleClick = (e, titleProps) => {
    const { index } = titleProps
    const { activeIndex } = this.state
    const newIndex = activeIndex === index ? -1 : index

    this.setState({ activeIndex: newIndex });

  }

  render() {
    const { activeIndex } = this.state

    return (
      <Accordion styled>
        <Accordion.Title
          active={activeIndex === 1}
          index={1}
          onClick={this.handleClick}
        >
          <Post />

        </Accordion.Title>

        <Accordion.Content 
        active={activeIndex === 1}
        >
        <AudioPlayer />
          <p>
            This is the content that I would like to scroll to
          </p>
        </Accordion.Content>
      </Accordion>

    )
  }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView 
This will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use below to autoscroll through contents. I have shown an example with drop down click. You can change as per your requirement

```
import { Accordion } from "semantic-ui-react";
import Post from "./Post";
import AudioPlayer from "./AudioPlayer";
export default class PostContent extends Component {
 state = { activeIndexs: [] };
 handleClick = (e, titleProps) => {
   const { index } = titleProps;
   const { activeIndexs } = this.state;
   const newIndex = activeIndexs;
   const currentIndexPosition = activeIndexs.indexOf(index);
   if (currentIndexPosition > -1) {
     newIndex.splice(currentIndexPosition, 1);
   } else {
     newIndex.push(index);
   }
   this.setState({ activeIndexs: newIndex });
 };
 render() {
   const { activeIndexs } = this.state;
   return (
     <Accordion styled>
       <Accordion.Title
         active={activeIndexs.includes(0)}
         index={0}
         onClick={this.handleClick}
       />
       <Accordion.Content active={activeIndexs.includes(0)}>
         <p>This is the content that I would like to scroll to</p>
       </Accordion.Content>
       <Accordion.Title
         active={activeIndexs.includes(1)}
         index={1}
         onClick={this.handleClick}
       />
       <Accordion.Content active={activeIndexs.includes(1)}>
         <p>This is the content that I would like to scroll to</p>
       </Accordion.Content>
       <Accordion.Title
         active={activeIndexs.includes(2)}
         index={2}
         onClick={this.handleClick}
       />
       <Accordion.Content active={activeIndexs.includes(2)}>
         <p>This is the content that I would like to scroll to</p>
       </Accordion.Content>
       <Accordion.Title
         active={activeIndexs.includes(3)}
         index={3}
         onClick={this.handleClick}
       />
       <Accordion.Content active={activeIndexs.includes(3)}>
         <p>This is the content that I would like to scroll to</p>
       </Accordion.Content>
       <Accordion.Title
         active={activeIndexs.includes(4)}
         index={4}
         onClick={this.handleClick}
       />
       <Accordion.Content active={activeIndexs.includes(4)}>
         <p>his is the content that I would like to scroll</p>
       </Accordion.Content>
     </Accordion>
   );
 }
}
```